# Can't make CSS Margin from Bootstrap Template disappear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hope someone can help me here.

I have this:
http://jsfiddle.net/8dCyz/

It is responsive, so and you will only be able to see the problem, when you have the menu not toggled in mobile form.

Anyway. There appears to be a margin, which I don't know where it is coming from, because it doesn't come from the anchor tags inside the ul>li. And Chrome Developer Tools doesn't hightlight anything, when I hover above it.

Here is an image, that explains exactly what I mean.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTSzw.png

Does anyone know, where and how I get rid of this margin? (or padding or whatever it is?)

I tried playing around with this but to no avail:

```
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
```

Comment: Just to make things clear, you are trying to remove the space between the gray background of a link and the horizontal line?

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem here is with this property:

```
padding-bottom:30.5px
```

On this selector

```
.navbar-nav > li > a
```

This is affecting you social buttons who has a bigger height that your other `a` tags then you need a special style for those buttons: I have added an `id` to select the `ul` for social buttons:

```
#social > li > a {
 padding-bottom:18px;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/8dCyz/7/**